# When using 'Replace' built in function in T-SQL within a Select Query, does the data on the table get modified?

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

I have the following query

```
SELECT  
    [DocID],
    [Docunum],
    [Comments] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Comments], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
FROM 
    [Billy].[dbo].[order]
WHERE
    DocDate = '2017-12-20 00:00:00.000'
```

I was wondering if the replace function, actually changes the value in the database? My concern is that this is ERP and I do not want referential integrity problems. I only want to eliminate the carriage separators from the `NVARCHAR` column to avoid spacing issues while pasting in Excel. I do not want any values changed in the database.

Any feedback would be appreciated. I have searched and did not find anything that answered this specifically. If I missed something please post link for reference if possible.

Comment: Does the `replace()` appear in an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: In your case of a `SELECT`, the `REPLACE` is **only** applied to the values as they are being returned from the database - this does **NOT** affect the database values at all

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  Very clear and concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here you are using replace in Select query so it will not affect your database it will only affect your result which is returned by this query, so here you are safe.

Comment: Thank you Aditya, I am grateful for your response.